# Getting Null Object Reference error while trying to run androidTest on SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, testing, junit

I am trying to create a test case for my SQLite DB in a small project.

This code snippet works fine on MainActivity.java:

```
FileDbHelper dbHelper = new FileDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

When I try to run the Application Test (androidTest) with following lines in it, I get an error:

```
FileDbHelper dbHelper = new FileDbHelper(mContext);
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // error I get is referring to this line (line 28).
```

Specific error I get is this:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor:
>   testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly (java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory,
>   android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>   at
>   com.permasse.apps.file.android.ApplicationTest.(ApplicationTest.java:28) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) at
>   junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:118) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:149) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:57)
>   at
>   android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:78)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:444)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:425)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:371)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4933)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) ) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176) at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1976)

I tried to change the context to getApplication.getApplicationContext() but then it throw an error on line 26.

If I understand right, test class cannot get the reference to the database since it is returning a null object. But why? Is it an error about the context?

**UPDATE**

Both of the following lines throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
String dbaddress1 = mContext.getDatabasePath("file.db").toString();
String dbaddress2 = getContext().getDatabasePath("file.db").toString();
```

I am pretty sure this is an error related to context, but have no idea about how to solve it.

**UPDATE**

It turnes out I was stupid enough to write my tests to ApplicationTest() function. One should write test methods seperately, and name of the test functions should start with test. such as testMethod1() (found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8787346/2960978) SO answer).

But now I am getting "Empty test suite" error. Will update as I progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It is all because of not reading the freaking manual. Adding these dependencies to the build.gradle did the trick.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
```

As outlined in this [Android Developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)

Just make sure the com.android.support:support-annotations version matches with your compile version.

Answer (score 0):

use this for get write-readable SQLiteDatabase:

```
 SQLiteDatabase database;
 String DATABASE_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath("your db name").toString();
 public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
 database =    SQLiteDatabase.
 openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
 }
```

Comment: Not working, getting the same error : `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testApplicationTestCaseSetUpProperly (java.lang.NullPointerException`. I could not used myContext though, I had to use mContext. Where does that myContext comes from? Should I define it somewhere in my code? 

Also, what is the underlying reason that I cannot just use the same code as I use in my MainActivity.java?